# Combining CSS files into a single cached one

Tags: theme-development, css

I'm creating a theme where i want it to have different widgets and plugins. Each plugin would ideally have it's own css file. However, this approach is not so good because i can end up having multiple files included in my header.

Is there an approach where i can sort of cache all different css files in a single one upon the first user request and then just use that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: put them all in a function, and then enqueue that function at the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. That way, you can define the CSS dynamically (e.g. based on Theme option settings), and let WordPress output it in the document head.

Comment: +1 That sounds interesting, but it would still load different css files right ? Is it possible to load a single one using that or an altered technique?

Comment: No; it would just output multiple `<script>` calls in the document head.

Answer (score 1):

[W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) is your friend. It has the ability to combine and concatenate js/css files out of the box. You'll have to do some manual configuration, but the pros outweigh the cons.

Answer (score 0):

[WP Minify](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/) does the job quite well too. Little easier to configure than W3TC and integrates nicely with WP Super Cache if you're already using it.